# Impact Forces in Blender Game Engine

Tags: python, game-engine, physics, collision

I am using the blender game engine to run drop test physics simulations and I was wondering if there is a way to collect the force and impact data from the collision. Maybe using "appliedImpulse"? I am using Python within the BGE and can already collect impact points. I am trying to find contact time and/or force. Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking to measure is a change in velocity. Look into [getLinearVelocity()](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_release/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.getLinearVelocity)

Comment: @Mentalist is there a way to check the change in velocity over time? For acceleration etc.

Comment: Yes. On each tick of the game engine, measure the linear velocity, and based on the difference between the current and last tick - do something. I used this approach to calculate fall damage and it worked pretty well. Make sure the object is using a compatible physics type, or it won't work.